# ArcGIS 10 GeoTIFF Export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, taudem

I'm not terribly familiar with ArcGIS in general, but I have a geodatabase (I think) containing a 3m DEM in ArcGis 9.3.

I would like to have this 3m DEM in a GeoTIFF file so I can do some processing with the TauDEM package.

I've tried right-clicking the 3m DEM layer and going to Export->Tiff, but it asks me what size (DPI, in essence) I want the exported TIFF to be.

If I put in a low DPI, the exported file size is too small to be the actual DEM and comparisons between the GeoTIFF image and my view on ArcGIS show that the TIFF is smoothed. If I put in a high DPI I can't open the TIFF, but I'm pretty sure the result wouldn't be what I wanted, based on the low-DPI test.

How do I export a GeoTIFF containing exactly the data in the 3m DEM layer without having to worry about resolution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would use the copy raster tool.  ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Raster > Copy Raster.  Just include .tif as the extension of your output file.