# .tif and .tfw to GeoTIFF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, envi

I have a .tiff and a .tfw file that I want to change into a GeoTIFF. When I try to open the file in ArcMap and ENVI 5.0, it is successful. However, in Google Earth it is not.

Is there anyway to create the GeoTiff in ArcMap or ENVI?

Comment: There's an older thread on this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/how-to-convert-a-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But I don't know how to use gdal so I was wondering if there is a way to do it without.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArcMap Copy Raster .tif not opening in Google Earth, Photoshop](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103520/arcmap-copy-raster-tif-not-opening-in-google-earth-photoshop) - if you have not received an answer to your first attempt at asking the please edit that to try and attract potential answerers.  You may find this [Meta Q&A](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) helpful.

Comment: I think this is actually a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20139/arcgis-10-geotiff-export?rq=1 and more detailed information about geotiffs and world files can be found at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64599/geotiff-explanation-of-aux-xml-and-tfw-world-file Are you sure your tif isn't already a geotiff, and just has the world file along for the ride?

Answer (score 1):

Install qgis, it uses gdal and the user interface it isn't so different from Esri sw

Answer (score 1):

I like the QGIS answer, that's one way to get GDAL, and probably the least confusing.

The question was for ArcGis or ENVI, I can't comment on ENVI but in ArcGis use the [Raster to Other Format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000032000000) tool which is available from ArcCatalog by selecting the rasters, right clicking, and selecting *Raster to Other Format (multiple)* from the popup menu. Select the output as TIFF and specify the output folder which will read and write the images from world tif to GeoTiff and as an added bonus, depending on your geoprocessing environments, will build pyramids and calculate statistics.

Don't forget to set the spatial reference for the images, either using [Batch Define Spatial Reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00pv00000012000000) or individually.