# GeoTIFF created using ArcGIS for Desktop not displaying in Google Earth or Photoshop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, google-earth, envi

I originally had an IMAGINE Land Cover raster file that I opened in ArcMap.

I used the Extract Feature from Raster to extract only the Developed class and saved it (still IMAGINE).

Then I used the Copy Raster to convert the IMAGINE to GeoTIFF, but when I try to view the GeoTiff in Google Earth or Photoshop, it doesn't display anything.

However, in ENVI, it displayed successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You make no mention of the Coordinate System for your raster data so I suspect that it is different from that used by Google Earth.

The [Google Earth projection](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148110?hl=en) page says:

> Google Earth uses Simple Cylindrical projection with a WGS84 datum for
>   its imagery base.

Use the Properties of your raster dataset(s) to check the coordinate system(s) being used.  If they are not the same as Google Earth is using, and you want to display them there then use the [Project Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007q000000) tool to project them.